# How can I display bootstrap card horizontally in jinja 2 for each loop?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, bootstrap-4

Im having a difficulty in displaying bootstrap cards using for each loop in a horizontal fashion, because it will be displayed vertically by standard.

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
            {% for game in gamest %}
            <div class="card card-inverse card-primary " style="width: 20rem;">
              <div class="card-block">
                <div class="text-xs-center">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                <p class="card-title"><b>{{ game['status2'] }}</b></p>
                <p class="card-title">{{ game['matchtype2'] }}</p>
                <p class="card-title">{{ game['teams2'] }}</p>
                {% if game['Batting team'] %}
                <p class="card-text">{{ game['Batting team'] }}<b>{{" "}}{{ game['runs10'] }}/{{ game['wickets10'] }}{{" "}}({{ game['overs10'] }}{{" "}}ov)</b></p>
                {% endif %}
                <p class="card-text">{{ game['name1'] }}{{" "}}<b>{{ game['runs1'] }}</b></p>
                <p class="card-text">{{ game['name2'] }}{{" "}}<b>{{ game['runs2'] }}</b></p>
                {% if game['name5'] %}
                <p class="card-text">{{ game['name5'] }}{{" "}}<b>({{ game['wickets5'] }}{{" "}}w)</b></p>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/Scorecard/{{ game["scorecardid"]}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Scorecard</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/Commentary/{{ game["commentaryid"]}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Commentary</a></div>
 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

this is what i'm getting [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the width (`style="width: 20rem;`) on the cards, and contain each card in a grid column. Then, iterate the `col-lg-3` in the loop...

```
<div class="row">
    {% for game in gamest %}
       <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
                  <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="text-xs-center">
                      <ul class="pagination">
                    <p class="card-title"><b>{{ game['status2'] }}</b></p>
                    <p class="card-title">{{ game['matchtype2'] }}</p>
                    <p class="card-title">{{ game['teams2'] }}</p>
                    {% if game['Batting team'] %}
                    <p class="card-text">{{ game['Batting team'] }}<b>{{" "}}{{ game['runs10'] }}/{{ game['wickets10'] }}{{" "}}({{ game['overs10'] }}{{" "}}ov)</b></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <p class="card-text">{{ game['name1'] }}{{" "}}<b>{{ game['runs1'] }}</b></p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ game['name2'] }}{{" "}}<b>{{ game['runs2'] }}</b></p>
                    {% if game['name5'] %}
                    <p class="card-text">{{ game['name5'] }}{{" "}}<b>({{ game['wickets5'] }}{{" "}}w)</b></p>
                    {% endif %}
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right row">
                  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/Scorecard/{{ game["scorecardid"]}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Scorecard</a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/Commentary/{{ game["commentaryid"]}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Commentary</a></div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Also, the btn-group shouldn't be combined with the `row`>`cols`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the buttons row.

Comment: thanks @ZimSystem it worked like a charm, I put that button group to seperate distance between two buttons or it will be attached to eachother.